# Add value from inputs to array if not exists

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, object

I am rendering in my React application an `Array` and for each Array I have an `input` element.
This elements gets as `name` the `ID` from the Array entryand a value can be entered.

I have a `handleChange()` functions, which gets the `ID` and the `input value`.

This data should be added to an Array, which I want to save to my `State`.

Later on, I have for each Array entry a `Submit` button, where I have to send the input value to an API endpoint.

```
constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        sendTransferObj: []
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

...

handleChange(transId: string, event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    console.log(transId, event.target.value); // returns => '123', '1'

    let inputObject = [{ id: transId, value: event.target.value }]
    let arrayForState = [];

    const index = inputObject.findIndex(inputObject => inputObject.id != transId)

    if (index === -1) {
        arrayForState.push(inputObject);
    } else {
        console.log("object already exists")
    }

    console.log(arrayForState)

    this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        sendTransferObj: arrayForState
    }); // error!
}

...

<Form.Control as="input" name={trans.id} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, trans.id)} />
```

My problem is currently in my `handleChange()`, where the input value gets saved to my `arrayForObject` for one input, but if I enter in a second input element a value, it gets overwritten.

Also I get various errors, when I later want to do a `setState()` for save this Array.

This is my whole component which I am using for reference (getting the Array that I render from my state with Redux): https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-ptolemy-69zbu?fontsize=14&theme=dark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to append the inputObject to the sendTransferObj array in the current state instead of appending it to a new empty array (which will cause the overwriting). You can do this using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
handleChange(transId: string, event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    let inputObject = [{ id: transId, value: event.target.value }]
    const index = inputObject.findIndex(inputObject => inputObject.id != transId)

    this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        sendTransferObj: index === -1 ? [
          ...this.state.sendTransferObj,
          inputObject
        ] : this.state.sendTransferObj
    });
}
```

This won't update the field when the `inputObject` is found, though. I would recommend storing the values in an object with the ID as keys instead (and formatting it into the desired format when requesting the API). This way, you don't have to iterate through the array to find the matching object.

```js
constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        sendTransferObj: {}
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

...

handleChange(transId: string, event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
      this.setState({
          ...this.state,
          sendTransferObj: {
            ...sendTransferObj,
            [transId]: event.target.value
          }
      }); 
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your time to answer my question! @hbentlov
It works but the only problem left is, that for each input it adds a new object to the value: https://abload.de/img/screenshot2019-12-20a9fkkz.png

Comment: So if I enter `12`for example, it should be `[{id: '123', value: 12}]`and not two objects with `[{id: '123', value: 1}, {id: '123', value: 12}]` :)

Comment: I updated the answer suggesting using an object instead of an array to store the values.